# How to allocate memory to a C callback function with ctypes and threading

Tags: python, c, multithreading, ctypes

I'm currently writing python bindings for a camera software. The commercial SDK only contains the documentation and DLL. I do not have the C code but I'll try to be as clear as possible, so please bear with me.

I have all the library functions working but one: a callback function that acquires the pictures. The documentation only provides the function prototypes:

> foo: Starts image acquisition on specified port. Return error code.

```
int foo(HANDLE dev, char port, int queueMode, callback_type fnCallback, void * userInfo );
```

> callback_type: Application-defined callback function that recieves
>   information about acquired frame.

```
void callback_type(void * userInfo, photoStruct* photo);
```

This is my python code after loading the library and wrapping the functions and structures.

```
callback_type = WINFUNCTYPE(None,c_void_p,POINTER(photoStruct)) 
def my_callback(userInfo, photoInfo):
    if(photoInfo.status == 0):
        #Process incoming photo
        print "I'm here" #for debugging purposes
        q.put(photoInfo.rawBuffer[:photoInfo.bufferSize])
        q.task_done()
_my_callback = callback_type(my_callback)
```

Whenever I try to call foo for the first time:

```
 >>>lib.foo(dev, port, c_int(0), _my_callback, None)
```

I get Error code 4: Not enough memory to perform operation (according to the documentation).
When I call it again (and again), it returns always 0 which is success, but the queue stays empty and it never prints "I'm here".

I then tried adding a thread:

```
ty = threading.Thread(target=lib.foo, args=(dev,port, c_int(0), _my_callback, None))
>>> ty.start()   
>>> ty.run() 
line 758, in run
    del self.__target, self.__args, self.__kwargs  
AttributeError: _Thread__target
```

I also tried to just not use run() and call the function directly after starting the thread. It doesn't work still.
I don't really know what is going on here. I am very new to threading and ctypes but my guess is that the library uses its own thread to return the photos and I somehow should allocate memory for this callback function. But how?
Any solutions/comments would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**_ Edit: sample code from the documentation _**

```
* \sample
* \code
* void __stdcall callback_type(void* userInfo, photoStruct* photo)
* {
*   // Process incoming photo
* }
* ...
* foo(dev, port, 0, &callback_type, NULL);
* ...
* \endcode
*/
```

I tried to call foo in Python with

```
>>>lib.foo(dev, port, c_int(0), byref(_my_callback), None)
```

It stopped the program.

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand your question but `userInfo` is optional so I leave it as `None` and `photoInfo` is a structure `photoStruct` that I need.

Comment: Could you print userInfo and photoInfo in your callback function? Post the result here.

Comment: @Munchhausen OP is correct with `None` for return type.  `void` == `None`, `void*` == `c_void_p`.

Comment: @Munchhausen I can't I tried to print them from _my_callback but nothing happens

Comment: If nothing is printed, can we conclude that your callback is not called?

Comment: @Munchhausen yes, I believe it's not called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you went wrong without a complete example.  Did you declare `foo.argtypes`?  Are you sure the functions are `__stdcall` for use with `WinDLL` and `WINFUNCTYPE`, or are they `__cdecl` and need `CDLL` and `CFUNCTYPE`?

Here's a working example using the following test code for the DLL:

```
typedef void* HANDLE;

typedef struct {
    int value;
} photoStruct;

typedef void (__stdcall * callback_type)(void * userInfo, photoStruct* photo);

__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall foo(HANDLE dev, char port, int queueMode, callback_type fnCallback, void * userInfo)
{
    photoStruct p;
    p.value = 123;
    fnCallback(userInfo, &p);
    return 0;
}
```

Python code:

```
#!python2
from ctypes import *
HANDLE = c_void_p

class photoStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('value',c_int)]
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'photoStruct(value={})'.format(self.value)

callback_type = WINFUNCTYPE(None,c_void_p,POINTER(photoStruct))

@callback_type
def my_callback(userInfo, photo):
    print userInfo,photo.contents

foo = WinDLL('test').foo
foo.argtypes = (HANDLE,c_char,c_int,callback_type,c_void_p)
foo.restype = c_int

foo(1,'2',3,my_callback,None)
```

Output:

```
None photoStruct(value=123)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I still get the same error: not enough memory. The function are stdcall. From lib.h `typedef void (__stdcall *callback_type)(void* useInfo, photoStruct* photoInfo);`

Comment: @Unicorn This works for me with Python 2 (32-bit) on Windows 10.  Did you compile this exact DLL example and use this exact Python code?  If you used your own DLL, there must be a difference in the function declarations.

Comment: @Unicorn Also, if using your actual DLL, can you call the same functions with a similar callback in C?  Maybe the API is used incorrectly.  How big is the `photoInfo.rawBuffer`?  That might be duplicated through ctypes and exceed your virtual memory space in a 32-bit app (if it is 32-bit).

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 64bit. I'm going to check that now and post the result. Ps: I added the sample code from the documentation to my question.

Comment: @Unicorn I built a Python 3 64-bit version of the above code and it works as well (after changing to print *function*).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It helped me realized that the API is used incorrectly!